# Determine set of points in the complex plane that satisfies the following equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Thanks for taking your time.

I've been given the following problem:

Determine and plot set of points in the complex plane that satisfies the following equation

$ |z-2| + |z+2|=5 $

where $ z = x+iy$.

My first approach was to square both sides, but what I ultimately get is the square of a binomial, which when expanded gives me the product of square roots:

$ 2\sqrt{((x+2)^2+y^2)((x-2)^2+y^2)}$

which I don't know what to do with.

Can anyone provide some insight? Tanks!

Comment: You should get an **equation** after your manipulations. Anyway, what does the condition $|z+2|+|z-2|=5$ mean geometrically?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It is not a duplicate.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for your answer. While solving these problems, geometrically I always tend to get a circle. I suspect this might be an elipse but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Perhaps if you try to answer my quastion will help.

Comment: @Aqua I'm on it. I can't type faster than I currently am typing.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- Do you know what is a geometric meaning of $|z-w|$?
- Do you know the definition of particular conic sections?

Comment: Specifically $|z-w|$? No. As I said, while doing these exercises I usually get equations of circles. I can't 

As for the definition, yes I'm aware of it! Thanks for answering.